# run grep cmd recursively and print path name and result

Tags: shell-script, grep, find

I have a log file that exists in multiple directories one for each client.  I am trying to run the following:

```
find . -iname "20140926.log" -exec cat {} \; | grep 123456 | grep 'food="100"' | wc -l
```

this returns me the result I want but I want to know for each fullpath what the individual count was. For example I tried this:

```
for f in "/path/*"; do
  result=`eval grep 123456 "$f/logs/20140926.log" | grep 'food="100"' | wc -l`
  echo "$f - $result" 
done
```

But it just returning a list of all my directories and then the final result. I am expecting something like this:

```
/path1/log/file.log - 0
/path2/log/file.log - 2
/path3/log/file.log - 39
etc...
```

This way I can see the wc for my grep for each path/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -H` will print file names for you, but since you're doing multiple greps you can just echo the file name yourself:

```
for f in $(find . -name '20140926.log'); do
    echo -n "$f "
    grep 123456 $f | grep -c 'food="100"'   # grep -c prints count of matches
done
```

Comment: This will break on even a simple space, let alone harder things. Using a `for` loop to iterate over arbitrary text is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
find . -name 20140926.log | while read file; do 
    printf "%s - " "$file "; grep 123456 $file | grep -c 'food=100' 
done
```

This has the advantage of not breaking on file names with spaces. It does break on newlines and backslashes, however. If your files can be completely unreasonable, use this:

```
find . -name 20140926.log | while read -rd '' file; do 
    printf "%s - " "$file "; grep 123456 "$file" | grep -c 'food=100'      
done
```